# Windows registry application crash

Tags: .net, c++, registry

I don't even know what exactly should I ask, so I need mostly some advices, ideas, possible reasons ...

So, the problem is the following: 
I have an application that should run whenever a user logs-on to the computer. The application is working fine when its lunched from it's shortcut or from the main executable. I have put a registry key in:

> HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run

which points to my application. I have also put an entry to the:

> HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\App Paths\My Application.exe

to specify the working directory because the application needs a configuration file (XML). Despite all these, the application continues crashing whenever I start my computer with the message ".exe has encountered a problem and needs to close" with the option to debug it, but when I hit the debug button it doesn't appear anything.

I don't know exactly what is the problem so any suggestion will be well received.

**Solved problem:**

Problem was solved but I still have some question marks which I have to study. Anyway, for some unknown (yet) reason if I put the working folder path into

> HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\App Paths\My Application.exe

registry doesn't have any effect. So the solution was to write this path into the

> HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run

registry in the following way:

CMD /C START "" /D "working directory path" "completely path to exe".

This solution seems to work well. 
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: have you put a shortcut to it in the `startup` folder and tried that?

Comment: Yes and that works, but the requirement is to use registry keys.

Comment: It is probably an issue with the current directory. You can use the `Image File Execution Options` registry key to force your application to run under the debugger when it launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a Dr Watson log on disk, and if you don't find one, configure a test system to generate one.  Search google for instructions, it's straightforward.

Once you have a log file, search for "fault ->" in the file, and it will tell you the address of the assembly that is crashing.  If you're lucky, it will provide a function for you, but you may need to pair the log file with a matching .map to look up the crash address and associate it with a line of code / function.  Additionally, debugging the matching source, in release mode, with Debug > Windows  > Disassembly will also show you exact memory addresses, that you can match up with the "fault ->" line in the dr watson log.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the source code you can write a log file detailing where the program gets up to before it crashes, this should give you more specific details, windows 7 is very restrictive with this, so consider using [Task Scheduler](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/67503-task-create-run-program-startup-log.html)

you may need to put the full path in the:
`HKLM\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\App Paths\My Application.exe`
key to get the right application context.
e.g.
`path: C:\My Folder\`

[Source here for registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#appPaths)